# Seeing if value at first index is a number

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress site where 100,000+ spam accounts have been made. Although there are other types as well but many of them seem to have a user name that starts with a number.

So I wanted to ask whether there can be a `MYSQL` query to `select/delete` all users whose username starts with a number.

An extension to this question is that whether those users need to be deleted from the users table only or also the user-meta or other tables.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: As a side note, you should get the word fence plugin to enhance security

Comment: thank you for the comment. have used si captcha but still issue seems to persist :). (also using buddypress registration)

Comment: on one of my WP sites I was having a similar problem and I didn't really want users to register anyway unless specifically allowed so I simply put an htaccess password on the registration page. Just a thought if you really don't care if anybody registers or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, there is (of course) MySQL query for almost everything, below query selects such users, you just need to run it couple of times:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login LIKE 'put_number_here%' OR user_nicename LIKE LIKE 'put_number_here%' OR display_name LIKE 'put_number_here%'
```

Replace the `put_number_here` with starting number and go on.

Then, after assuring that those users are not legit, you can delete them with almost the same query:

```
DELETE FROM wp_users WHERE user_login LIKE 'put_number_here%' OR user_nicename LIKE LIKE 'put_number_here%' OR display_name LIKE 'put_number_here%'
```

EDIT:
Here is the user defined function, which checks if the given value from a field is numeric.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ISNUMERIC(myVal VARCHAR(1024)) 
 RETURNS TINYINT(1) DETERMINISTIC 
 RETURN myVal REGEXP '^(-|\\+)?([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)$';
```

Comment: thank you. but is there any generic query (e.g a mysql function) to see if the first parameter is the number.

Comment: Nope, you have to create your own function (so called UDF). See my edit of the answer.

Comment: ok. thank you. will mark as answer. also can you tell that which wp tables hold info for a new user . are they only the users & user_meta tables ?

Comment: If you delete the records from `wp_users` table, the records from `wp_user_meta` will be not automatically removed (the both tables are not linked via foreign key).